# " MethodNotAllowedHttpException" while buiding an api for my andorid app using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, android, api, laravel-5.4

**AuthController.php code**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use JWTAuth;
 use App\User;
 use JWTAuthException;

 class AuthController extends Controller
{
 private $user;


 public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}   
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'email'=> 'required|email|unique:users',
            'first_name'=> 'required|max:120',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
            ]);   

    $user = $this->user->create([
    'name' => $request->get('name'),
    'email' => $request->get('email'),
    'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password'))
        ]);

    $user->save();
    if(!$user){
            return response()->json(['status'=>false,'message'=>'User not created']);
    }
    else {
        return response()->json(['status'=>true,'message'=>'User created successfully','data'=>$user]);
    }

}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'email'=> 'required',
            'password'=> 'required'
            ]);  

    $credentials = $request->only('email','password');
    $token = null;

    try {
        $token = $this->jwtauth->attepmt($credentials);
        if(!$token)
        {
            return response()->json(['invalid email or password'], 422);
        }
    }
    catch (JWTAuthException $ex) 
    {
         return response()->json(['failed to create token'], 500);
    }

     return response()->json(compact('token'));
}


public function getAuthUser(Request $request){
    $user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->token);
    return response()->json(['result' => $user]);
}
}
```

**api.php routes**

```
Route::post('register', 'api\AuthController@register');
Route::post('login', 'api\AuthController@login');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
Route::get('user', 'api\AuthController@getAuthUser');

});
```

*Im sure that there is something little  wrong im my code because the "getAuthUser" method is working and cheking if there is a token or no . I'll be thankful if anyone helped me *

Answer (score 0):

So, which one of the methods is giving you error?

Since you did specify that "getAuthUser" was working fine; And because of the kind of error you're getting I'm going to assume you're talking "register" and "login".

Anyway, that kind of error happens when you try to access a route with the incorrect kind of request. You must use a "POST" request, instead of a "GET" if you are trying to access /register and /login